# Fix state labels of HMM in depmixS4

Tags: r, hidden-markov-model

Everytime I fit my HMM, the obtained labels of states that I get are different. Sometimes State 1 is of negative mean and high std. deviation response parameters and sometimes State 2 is of negative mean and high std. deviation. I have tried setting seed `set.seed(1)` everytime I am fitting my model (multiple times in the same code block). Is there a way to set constraints in the fit function to always get label 1 as the label for the negative mean and high std. deviation state.

Answer (score 0):

In depmixS4, you can set constraints on the parameters through the `conrows`, `conrows.upper`, and `conrows.lower` arguments in the `fit` function. Through these arguments, you force the mean in state 1 to be lower than the mean in state 2 by setting a constraint on the difference between these means, e.g.
$$\overline{Y}_1  - \overline{Y}_2 < 0$$
For more information, there is an example in the help file for the `fit` function. See

```r
?depmixS4::fit
```

Another option would be to estimate the model as unconstrained, and then re-order the states afterwards. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62533421/13797727