# inequality constraints in mixture models using conrows in depmixS4

Tags: r, hidden-markov-model

I would like to fix the states identified by depmixS4 in a certain order to prevent label switching.  This question was asked here ([Fix state labels of HMM in depmixS4](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/525105/fix-state-labels-of-hmm-in-depmixs4)), and the answer given recommended the ?depmixS4::fit documentation for how to do this.  However, the documentation only has an example of how to use conrows to establish an equality constraint, not a constraint that one state's mean has to be higher than the other.
I have been running the example code given in the documentation using the "speed" data and trying to modify it to fix the slow controlled state as state 1, but nothing works.

I first fit the model without the constraint and replicate the tutorial results:

```
mod1 <- depmix(list(rt~1,corr~1),data=speed,transition=~Pacc,nstates=2,
               family=list(gaussian(),multinomial("identity")),ntimes=c(168,134,137))
# fit the model
set.seed(3)
fmod1 <- fit(mod1)
```

To switch the order of the states so that the longer RT state is first, I have tried:

```
conr <- matrix(0,1,18)
conr[1,11] <- 6
conr[1,15] <- 4
mod1h <- setpars(mod1,pars)
fmod3h <- fit(mod1h,conrows=conr) # using free defined above
```

and

```
conr <- matrix(0,1,18)
conr[1,11] <- 1
conr[1,15] <- 0
fmod3h <- fit(mod1,conrows=conr) # using free defined above
```

and several other variations on this approach, But so far I am gettig only nonsensical results, plus the warning:  solnp--> Solution not reliable....Problem Inverting Hessian.